# -[UIView initWithFrame:] returning nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uikit

The `UIView` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/initWithFrame:) states that `initWithFrame:` can return nil:

In which cases can this happen?

Comment: One case would be if the view is created through interface builder / storyboard.

Comment: @n00bProgrammer the documentation states that "`initWithFrame`" is ***not*** called if the view is loaded from a xib or storyboard file (`initWithCoder` is called instead).

Comment: Yes, I meant that. It is not called. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

An `NSObject` [can return `nil` from its initialiser method](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/init), and since `UIView` inherits from `NSObject`, it can return nil as well.

Unless there's a specific reason the object can't be created (e.g. as in the example they give, a camera object on a device with no camera) then you can always expect to get a return value.

You certainly wouldn't check if you got a value back every time. If there is some terrible low memory or resource situation which means nil is getting returned, your app is probably about to die anyway.

Comment: Ok, then the question shifts from when the init method of `UIView` can return `nil` to when the init method of `NSObject` can return nil. Is it only on low memory?

Comment: Btw, for `UIViewController` it's not documented that nil might be returned. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/Documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/initWithNibName:bundle: